# File data loss on Node server crash

Tags: node.js, file-io

I'm storing my main data part in JSON files (with changes written to MongoDB as well). I'm reading my tree structure from a file in sync mode, update the tree, then save it back to the file.

The problem is when I press "Stop" in debugger in VS code, my main file becomes blank (truncated). It happenes even when my file saving function has successfully completed its execution before the crash point, the line where an exception was thrown - I don't know why does it happen, maybe some OS disk caching?

I'm scared that data will be lost the same way on production server if Node crashes for some reason (e.g. low RAM).

How can I mitigate this issue? I need some transaction mechanism, like "keep the previous version of the file if anything goes wrong during request processing". I know I can write to a new file and then copy over the old one, or keep 2 files (last and second to last), but all that methods seem awkward.